# Filling array with class method

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to fill this array floorArray through the method fillUp in my Golv class.

This is the code from my main Class:

```
Golv golv = new Golv(this);

int[] floorArray = new int[FRAMEWIDTH];
golv.fillUp(floorArray);
```

And this is the relevant snippet from my Golv class:

```
public void fillUp(int[] floorArray){
    floorArray[0] = 5;
}
```

This produces ""VariableDeclaratorID" expected after this token." and "syntax error misplaced constructs" after the golv.fillUp(floorArray); row.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to add that statement - invocation, inside some method.

Comment: Note that it's unusual to use non-english variable/class names. Feel free to  name them whatever you want, but your next question might be a lot more complicated, and then it'd be a pity if only swedes could help.

Comment: Maybe try to create default constructor first.

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist did you created a constructor for Golv with argument of type of your second class..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just put your source code directly inside a class, you need to put it in a method.
**BAD:**

```
public class Test{

    System.out.println("Hello");

}
```

**GOOD:**

```
public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }

}
```

So, to wrap it up: *Every piece of code that for example executes a method HAS to be in a method block. You CAN declare (create) variables outside a method but if you ever execute a piece of code it has to be inside a method! (else it will give you an exception)*

**Edit**: Read [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419817/filling-array-with-class-method#comment27059781_18419817) on your question! Kᴇʏsᴇʀ is 100% right! Please use English for everything when you're programming/developing anything.. ALWAYS use english, it **WILL** help!

(also, I guess you are from Sweden because golv is a swedish word and your name is kinda swedish :P, I'm from sweden too :) )

**EDIT 2**: Changed all words from 'function' to 'method' because: *In Java there are methods, but no functions. – JB Nizet*